# I'm not using "android.permission.SEND_SMS" Permission in my apps

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

I'm sending sms from my apps using this method.

```
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", number, null)));
```

But I did not declare `android.permission.SEND_SMS` in manifest file. Will it create any problem to published apps? Or is it rejecte from google play store?

Comment: In short you do not need permission to fire an intent.

Comment: @ADM He is asking that **Will it create any problem to published apps?** I think its not duplicate.

Comment: @Billah You will not get any problem.

Comment: Yeah thats mentioned in accepted answer there that permission is not required. So if its not required then there is no problem .. Thats makes it duplicate . its just a Semantic ...

Comment: His question is that **his app will be allowed on playstore, or it will get suspended.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permission is not required for the Implicit Intent. It don't break any permission rule as this is the Implicit Intent.

It will not create any issue at the time of uploading app.

Answer (score -2):

google removed that app from playstore which has mainfiest permisiion for call and sms in january 2019. if you want to use then use normal implicit intent or sms retrival api..

Comment: what is the wrong answer in these above line and who is the guy who voted down please reply